# jQuery Autocomplete works, but results not visible

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, model-view-controller, autocomplete

[image: Autocomplete]

I'm using MVC and jQuery UI to get autocomplete on this text box and for whatever reason its not showing the results correctly. I have verified through the ActionResult and in browser that the results are returned just not displayed correctly. I already know jQuery and jQueryUI work because I have a datepicker below that works.

```
public ActionResult ProfessorFirstAutoComplete(string term)
    {
        var firstNameQuery = db.Professors.Where(pr => pr.FirstName.StartsWith(term));
        SelectList firstNames = new SelectList(firstNameQuery, "Id", "FirstName");

        return Json(firstNames, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#profFirstBox").autocomplete(
            {
                source: '@Url.Action("ProfessorFirstAutoComplete", "Events")'
            });
    })
</script>

<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Professor.FirstName, "First Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Professor.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "profFirstBox" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Professor, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: could you post the code you are working with ?

Comment: @DinoMyte added code